# Starting celery with a project's name as a command line parameter issued an error

Tags: python, django, celery, eventlet

I have a project under dev VM 'ubuntu/trusty'.
I use **virtualenv** with the following packages:

```
celery 3.1.23
eventlet 0.18.4
django 1.8.15
```

Python version is 3.4.3.

When I start a celery worker in this way:

```
celery worker --loglevel=INFO -P eventlet -c 3 -Q default -E -n default.queue -l INFO
```

It starts correctly, but all tasks stay in the '**pending**' state.

When I start it this way (with project's name in **'-A'** parameter):

```
celery worker -A meridian --loglevel=INFO -P eventlet -c 3 -Q default -E -n default.queue -l INFO
```

It issues an error:

```
(meridian)vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:/vagrant/meridian/meridian$ celery worker -A meridian --loglevel=INFO -P eventlet -c 3 -Q default -E -n default.queue -l INFO
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/meridian/lib/python3.4/site-packages/celery/app/utils.py", line 241, in find_app
    found = sym.app
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'app'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/meridian/bin/celery", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/meridian/lib/python3.4/site-packages/celery/__main__.py", line 30, in main
    main()
  File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/meridian/lib/python3.4/site-packages/celery/bin/celery.py", line 81, in main
    cmd.execute_from_commandline(argv)
  File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/meridian/lib/python3.4/site-packages/celery/bin/celery.py", line 793, in execute_from_commandline
    super(CeleryCommand, self).execute_from_commandline(argv)))
  File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/meridian/lib/python3.4/site-packages/celery/bin/base.py", line 309, in execute_from_commandline
    argv = self.setup_app_from_commandline(argv)
  File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/meridian/lib/python3.4/site-packages/celery/bin/base.py", line 469, in setup_app_from_commandline
    self.app = self.find_app(app)
  File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/meridian/lib/python3.4/site-packages/celery/bin/base.py", line 489, in find_app
    return find_app(app, symbol_by_name=self.symbol_by_name)
  File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/meridian/lib/python3.4/site-packages/celery/app/utils.py", line 246, in find_app
    found = sym.celery
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'celery'
```

Does anybody know how to fix that ?

Answer (score 1):

It seems your project (application) is not importable.

Your options:

- Create a proper Python package (setup.py), install it with `pip install /project/directory`. That will create *copy* of your files in `virtualenv/lib/python-version/site-packages/`. By the book, but rarely used approach.
- `pip install -e /project/directory` also requires setup.py, will symlink project into site-packages, so it's a one shot operation for each virtualenv. Widely used among package developers.
- Take care of `sys.path` in Python code, before your project is imported. Example:

  `import sys
  sys.path.append('/project/directory')`
- Take care of import directories via `PYTHONPATH` environment variable. Usual platform dependent `PATH` rules apply (entries separated by `:` everywhere but `;` on Windows). This way is very popular for deployment. Example in shell:

  `export PYTHONPATH=/project/directory
  exec /virtualenv/bin/celery worker ...`

Comment: Thanks, but I am not sure what did you mean with 'install your project in the same virtualenv'. The virtualenv creates special directory contains needed python libraries and/or particular python version, isn't it ? How I can 'install' project there ?

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution here:

http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html

The only thing I needed to do is added a file **celery.py** to the project's root directory and then added few lines to **init.py** placed in the same directory. See docs above.